# hibernate with out pojo classes

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm fetching object list from session.createSQLQuery().
I didnt make any pojo classes for it because I don't want it
This object contain 2 variables , I want to fetch those variables who can I

My code

```
    session = sessionfactory.openSession() ;

    query = session.createSQLQuery("select id from A_Cleanup") ;
    List Ids =  query.list() ;
    for (Iterator iterator = Ids.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); iterator.next()){
        query = session.createSQLQuery("select distinct rec_category, a_id from a_cdr where a_id in (select id from alerts where al_id = :aid)")
                .setParameter("aid", Long.parseLong(Ids.get(0).toString())) ;
        java.util.List result = query.list() ;
        System.out.println("printing class object" +result.get(0).getClass()) ;

    }
    session.close() ;
```

Question:

result.get(0) is a object contain value rec_category and  a_id. How can I fetch this variables ?

Answer (score 0):

The `result.get(0)` returns an `Object[]` (in this case with 2 elements). So cast it first to `Object[]`, then retrieve each element separately and cast them to their proper types.

```
Object[] foo = (Object[]) result.get(0);
System.out.println(foo[0] + " and " + foo[1]); // Then cast each one to their real types
```

Comment: How can I retrieve each one after object[] casting ?

Comment: Surely you know how to work with arrays. If not, it's quite weird that you would be working with Hibernate.